# How to stop Spring @Scheduled task on Tomcat7?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm building Java Web Project on Servlet 3.0, Spring 3, and some other stuff. 
I'm trying to use Spring's @Sheduled task.
 It is working fine, but when i undeploy war from Tomcat scheduled task continues running.How to stop it on Spring Container destroy?

***UPDATE***
 I've found what was the root of my problem - i instantiated Spring context twice. First time in web.xml as

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and second one in code like:

```
 context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] 
 {"/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-     context.xml",   "/WEB-INF/spring/beans.xml"});
```

So two instances of SheduledProcessor was created and ony one of them was destroyed. So spring destroys one it's aware about and second continues running making me to think that nothing was destroyed.
Removing ClassPathXmlApplicationContext solved my problem.

**Controller.java**

```
package a.b.c;
imports...

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ReceiverController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml", ReceiverController.class);
        return "index";
    }


}
```

**ScheduledProcessor.java**

```
package a.b.c;

imports..

@Service
public class ScheduledProcessor   {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledProcessor.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30000)
    public void process() {
        logger.info("Processing task");

    }

}
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c"/>
    <task:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Log file output :

> **03 Jul 2013 11:32:34,436 [ INFO ] (ScheduledProcessor.process:17)-> Processing task
>
>   11:33:04,439 [ INFO ] (ScheduledProcessor.process:17)-> Processing task
>
>   Jul 2013 11:33:06,913 [ INFO ] (XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose:1042)-> Closing
>   WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Test-servlet': startup date [Wed
>   Jul 03 11:32:21 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy 03 Jul 2013
>   11:33:06,914 [ INFO ]
>
>   (DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons:444)-> Destroying
>   singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a56058:
>   defining beans
>   [scheduledProcessor,receiverController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, etc..;
>   root of factory hierarchy 
>    **
> 03 Jul 2013 11:33:34,440  INFO -> Processing task 
>   
> 03 Jul 2013 12:34:0,440  INFO -> Processing task**

Comment: Probably `registerShutdownHook()` might help you.

Comment: I've changed my ApplicationContext to
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml", ReceiverController.class);  context.registerShutdownHook();
But still the same.